# Call PHP method with Ajax.Request

Tags: php, javascript, prototypejs

Whats the best way to call a certain method in a PHP file with Ajax.Request (using prototype)? I am submiting a form with Form.serialize, so I thought of adding a parameter (like the name of the method to call) and then check it on the server script.
Something like:

```
var params=Form.serialize("someform")+"&=method='check_data'";
new Ajax.Request('somescript.php',{method:'post',parameters:params,onSuccess:
function(response)
{ 
    .. do something with the response
```

And in somescript.php:

```
if($_POST["method"] == "check_data")
{
    check_data();
...
}
```

This would work, but Im sure theres a better or simpler way to call a remote method (ala MVC). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under no circumstances do this for normal PHP methods. It opens a big potential security hole. Even if you limit the commands that can be called that way, it's not a good way to go in the long run.

Either stay with what you already do: Define a list of commands that can be passed to the PHP script (e.g. `command=delete`, `command=update`, `command=copy`, whatever you need), and call them using `switch`.

Or use a class with methods that can be safely called from outside:

```
class myCommands
{
  function copy()  {  ... }
  function delete()  {  ... }
  function update()  {  ... }
 }
```

then, in the PHP file, pass through the command like

```
if (method_exists($class, $_POST["method"]))  
 call_user_func(array($class, $_POST["method"]));
```

Comment: You suggest the solution I posted but without passing the method name as parameter (something else like update, copy) and then check it on the php script and call the method I want?

Comment: Your solution is fine because it limits the range of functions that can be called. If you want to introduce a wildcard (i.e. direct calling of whatever is in `$_POST["method"]` I suggest doing this for the methods of a class name only as I show in my updated answer; otherwise it would be possible to execute any PHP function.